# How to move to another html page after validating the password in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, typeerror, addeventlistener

There are two html pages, the index.html and bankPage.html, I am trying to validate the user using a password on index.html and then if the password is right, he moves to bankPage.html page.
With window.location(or location) I am able to move to bankPage.HTML but after moving to the HTML page I get a TypeError becoz the button that I selected holds a value null in bankPage.html and the button is defined in index.html.

The error I get is- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')**

Here is the code

```
//just an array that holds the user info in objects(array of objects)
const accounts = [account1, account2, account3, account4];

const btnLogin = document.querySelector('.login__button');
const inputLoginUsername = document.querySelector('.login__input--user');
const inputLoginPassword = document.querySelector('.login__input--password');

// Even handlers for logging in from the index page to the bank page

let currentAccount;

btnLogin.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  currentAccount = accounts.find(function (acc) {
    return acc.owner === inputLoginUsername.value;
  });

  if (currentAccount?.password === inputLoginPassword.value) {
    //send to another page
    window.location = 'bankPage.html';
    
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it like this..

if (currentAccount?.password === inputLoginPassword.value) {}

is 'currentAccount?.password' this legal..??

Comment: Yes, seems to work for me.

Comment: Have you checked you've selected the button correctly..?? comment the redirection line and try to console something on the button click.

Comment: It worked with console.log .
So, what I think th problem is that on the index.html page we have the button so the button got some value there but when we move to the bankPage.html after clicking the button, the value of the button becomes null becoz there is no button on that page.